# Image slider slide in/out

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to get the animation to slide 1st image out then 2nd image slide in, 2nd image slide out, 3rd image slide in and so on, as the code stands each image slides out fine but fades back in rather then sliding.

```
var s = 0,
    t = 2000;

$(document).on('ready', slide);

function slide(){
 var speed = setInterval(slider, t);
}

function slider(){
 s++;
 var sld  = $('#slider img'),
     imgs = sld.length;
 if(s == imgs){
 s = 0;
 }

sld.animate({'marginLeft': '+=750px'}, t).fadeOut('fast').animate({'marginLeft': '-=750px'}, t).eq(s).fadeIn(t);
}
```

[jFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EVSkT/)

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/EVSkT/9/)?

Comment: Yes that's it but without the fade out/in just slide out/in

Comment: I also want the images to not be seen outside the black border: http://jsfiddle.net/EVSkT/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should first change a bit the structure using an unordered list (`<ul>`):

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/750x250/75c8c8/fff&text=1"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/750x250/b775c8/fff&text=2"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/750x250/c8bd75/fff&text=3"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/750x250/c87575/fff&text=4"></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Then we should use a `setTimeout()` instead of a setInterval so to be sure that the next slide is launched once the animation is completed:

```
var s = 0,
    t = 2000,
    timer;

$(document).on('ready', slide);

function slide(){
    timer = setTimeout(slider, t);
}

function slider(){
    s++;
    var sld  = $('#slider li'),
    imgs = sld.length;
    if(s == imgs){
        s = 0;
    }
    sld.eq(s-1).animate({'left': '750px'}, t, function() {
        sld.eq(s).animate({'left': '0px'}, t, function() {
            speed = setTimeout(slider, t);
        });
    });
}
```

This way we slide the image right, then the next one left and finally call the `slider()´ function again with a timeout.

To make this work we need to change the css code like this:

```
#slider {
    height:250px;
    width:750px;
    margin:20px auto;
}

#slider ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
}

#slider​ ul li {
    position: absolute;
    left: 750px;
}

#slider ul li​:first-child {
    left: 0px;
}​
```

Here you can see a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/EVSkT/13/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the .fadeOut/.fadeIn with the .slideToggle

```
sld.animate({'marginLeft': '+=750px'}, t)
    .slideToggle('fast')
    .animate({'marginLeft': '-=750px'}, t)
    .eq(s)
    .slideToggle(t);
```

Comment: That dosen't seem to work for me, I am having better luck with hide/show but timing is now the problem.